# Can I request a token with a lifespan shorter than 1 hour?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm requesting an access token via Azure AD, using the address:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

The token returns correctly, however, the default lifespan of the token is 1 hour. Looking at the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token), there doesn't appear to be a parameter I can pass to request a token with a custom lifespan.

Is it possible to request a token with a short(er) lifespan?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can configure your [Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-lifetime-policy-properties) token lifetime [minimum 10 minutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-lifetime-policy-properties).

You could use following power-shell command to create your token lifetime policy.

```
$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"02:00:00","MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor":"00:10:00"}}') -DisplayName "WebPolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

For more details you could have a look these [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#example-create-a-policy-for-web-sign-in).

### Note

[Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory is now in (Preview) which is not recommended to use on production](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes)

Comment: Pretty sure this is the correct answer, however, when I try to apply that policy to an application with Azure AD using `Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy` I get: `Message: Policy operations on v2 application are disabled.` Which is unfortunate!

Comment: Its in preview, soon all the feature will be available. Did you created policy which is prerequisite please have a check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#prerequisites)

Comment: Yep I did. It's a [known issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell-azuread/issues/224) with V2 Azure AD Apps. So no way around that as far as I'm aware